# Burninate [star]?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

The [star](/questions/tagged/star) tag seems to have no centric meaning or focus.  It has been used to mean the [shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3540110/draw-a-star-using-imagefilledpolygon-with-diagram), a [rating system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1551016/star-rating-widget-for-jquery-ui), the [character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/916770/batch-file-password-stars-circles), the [Google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126089/how-to-star-a-url-in-google-search-programatically) [indicator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15819847/star-a-gmail-message-with-google-script), the [logical operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15606616/r-tree-reinsert), and the [network type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14699844/java-and-android-mesh-star-networking).

There are currently only 74 questions tagged with it and 4 followers.

[image: Burninating the countryside... burninating the people]

Comment: Aren't most stars burninating themselves, already? (referring both to the celestial bodies and the people...)

Comment: @AndrewBarber that can't be right, as our friend troggy burninates only the peasants. Quite clearly, stars are above peasants in ranking, so their cottages remain fine.

Comment: Hmmmm... you could have a point there, @RichardJ.RossIII

Comment: @AndrewBarber I take my trogdor lore quite seriously.

Comment: go supernova on it!

Comment: *...and the people*.  i c wut u did thar.

Comment: Ahhh, references to seminal sci-fi texts by one Mr Card are becoming more and more controversial @UV-D due to his stance on pretty much, well, everything. It's a pity, I like what he writes but not what he says...

Comment: Who is Mr. Card?

Comment: Orson Scott Card, I assume.  Though I'm not sure what the supernova was supposed to reference. :)

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards absolutely agree.

Comment: @bmike Why adding this tag? We should close those question as "pertains only to a specific site", and let them be buried away, or mass migrated as some point.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I am voting to close - but the tag helps me see that it's really SO specific when I was reviewing other's close votes so I'm adding them whilst doing some clean up. I wonder if a script should just nuke all posts with burninate and delete them from MSE. What small percentage of posts that were actually on-topic would take less manpower to recreate than the current review workload to clear out the old MSO stuff.

Comment: @bmike I see, it's just bumping tons of useless stuff to the front page.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Is there consensus to just leave that crud on this site? Bumping is how changes get noticed and critical mass to be closed, no?

Comment: @bmike there is automatic process that throw retag requests to the close queue, so as far as I can tell, no need to bump any of them.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Cool - I'll move my thoughts over here - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240368/is-there-a-process-set-up-to-clear-so-specific-tag-questions-on-mse

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yes, this question was created on Meta StackOverflow.

Comment: @bmike Yes, this question was created on Meta StackOverflow.