# Is there a process set up to clear SO specific tag questions on MSE

Tags: discussion, tags, review, burninate-system

As a new reviewer, I'm seeing lots of questions that deserve to be closed here since they were tag burninate requests specific to Stack Overflow.

Is there some software process set up to send these to the review queue automatically? If so, does it need any manual action like users making sure that questions have a specific tag or words so that they will eventually get reviewed for closure?

Basically, what actions can/should people with close rep take to help make this MSE and not MSO with respect to questions dealing with tags that were asked before the split of MSO/MSE.

Answer (score 4):

Someone is going through old open questions *manually* and flagging those posts for closure.

If you feel like it, you can help out, but take into account that there aren't all that many reviewers and we only have 20 reviews per day. Don't overload the queue!

Comment: Sure about that? Usually when there is a flag I can see that in the close dialog. When I'm first to review a retag it has no indication of such a flag and yet it's in the queue

Comment: @ShadowWizard: absolutely. I can see posts that have a close *reason* attached but no close *votes*. That always means the post was flagged instead.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: the time of day the posts appear also varies, there are often suggested edits on older posts coming in around the same time, etc. Someone is cleaning up manually.

Comment: This was my impression on what was happening and I've been reviewing for some time. I figured it was my time to also kick a few into the queue. I'll be sure to pace it - 4 or so at a time.